# QString string/text formatting

Tags: qt, formatting, qstring

I am trying to format a QString using the arg() function as follows:

```
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::blue, this);

....

QString tStr = QString("R: %1 G: %2 B: %3").arg( color.red(), color.green(), color.blue());
```

Here I get a 'integer division by zero exception'.

Background: using Qt add-in in VS 2010. Brand new to Qt framework.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should change that line to

```
QString tStr = QString("R: %1 G: %2 B: %3")
    .arg(color.red()).arg(color.green()).arg(color.blue());
```

I can only assume that your code is mapping to this overload of `arg()`

```
QString QString::arg(int a, int fieldWidth = 0, int base = 10, 
    const QChar & fillChar = QLatin1Char( ' ' )) const
```

I'm surprised that it is resulting in a division by zero error because nobody performs division without checking for 0 first or catching the exception :) Anyway, I ran a test here of your code on Qt 4.7.4 / Windows 7 / MinGW without an error, just the wrong result string.

Comment: Checked your code and it works. It's obvious what the misunderstanding was with the arg() function. Coming from a xprintf() and String.Format() planet this syntax seems a bit strange. However we live and we learn :). Thank you much.